# Rails 'stringify_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(sorry for my english)

I'm trying my first rails web app.
Here is my code:

Model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base    

   attr_accessible :about, :title, :url

end
```

Controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show

    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])

  end

  def update

    @mov = Movie.find(params[:id])

    if @mov.update_attributes(params[:id])

        redirect_to movies_path, :notice => "Your movie has been updated."

    else

        render "show"

    end  
  end


  def destroy

  end

end
```

- and the View

> ```
>     <%= form_for @movie do |m| %>
> <center>
>   <table>
>     <td valign='middle' align='right'>
>       Title:
>     </td>
>     <td>
>       <%= m.text_field :title %>
>     </td>
> <tr>
>     <td valign='middle' align='right'>
>       Description:
>     </td>
>     <td>
>       <%= m.text_area :about %>
>     </td>
> <tr>
>     <td valign='middle' align='right'>
>       URL:
>     </td>
>     <td>
>      <%= m.text_field :url, :id => "url" %><input type='file' onchange="document.getElementById('url').value = this.value" />
>     </td>
> <tr>
>     <td>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>       <center>
>         <%= m.submit %>
>       </center>
>     </td>
>   </table>
> </center>
> <% end %>
> ```

so this is an `update` action and this give an error message after press the update form button
error is:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "15":String
```

so I try again with `Movie.find(params[:id].to_i)` and the output is:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for 15:Fixnum
```

thanks for answers, have a good day!=)

Comment: use Movie.find(params[:id].to_i) and use @mov.update_attributes(params[:movie]) instead of @mov.update_attributes(params[:id])

Comment: May be issue with @mov.update_attributes(params[:id]) line. you have passed params[:id] but this is wrong you have to pass params[:movie].

Comment: The line number comes in handy when looking at the error.... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if @mov.update_attributes(params[:id])
```

Its because of the above line. Here you are trying to update the **@mov** attribute with the **params[:id]** which is wrong.

the **update** action in the controller should be as follow.

```
def update
  @mov = Movie.find(params[:id])
  if @mov.update_attributes(params[:movie])
    redirect_to movies_path, :notice => "Your movie has been updated."
  else
    render "show"
  end
end
```

Basically the **update_attributes** will check for hash as a parameter like below.

```
@mov.update_attributes(:about => "Sample About", :title => "Sample Title", :url => "Sample URL")
```